# Search service databases - How to get "database is too old and upgrade is required"

Tags: search, upgrade

In one SP server at a customer site we have the following scenario:

[image]

Customer upgraded from 2010 to 2013 sometime back but I don't have much details of this upgrade.

How can I simulate the same scenario in a lab environment such that these two DBs are in this state?

Thanks.

Comment: they probably sharepoint versioned upgraded but not sql server upgraded?

Comment: check this one http://blogs.technet.com/b/balasm/archive/2012/05/18/database-is-too-old-and-upgrade-is-required.aspx

Comment: do you have other search database, i think this is left over and above blog will solve the problem.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Thanks, I will try those steps. Problem faced by customer is that search results only show items that were created while they were in 2010. New items created after migration to 2013 are not in search.